Setting field.required to false cause error list indices must be integers or slices, not str
I want to set a page to update a user information, including a field to create a new password. This page is strictly for updating existing user. The password field in this page will be optional.
There is another page with another view to create user where the password field is required there.
My current approach is to set the field required to be false in the view as below
class User(AbstractUser):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ommited the rest for brevity

class UserEdit(UpdateView):
    model = User 
    fields = ['fullname', 'username','status','email','phone_number','role','program_studi','password']
    template_name = 'user-management-edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user-management')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['password'] = ''
        self.fields['password'].required = False
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.edited_by = self.request.user
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
        if password:
            form.instance.set_password(password)
        return super().form_valid(form)

{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name in inline_field %}
        <div class="col-4">
            {% if field.field.required %}
                {% bootstrap_field field label_class='control-label required' %}
            {% else %}
                {% bootstrap_field field %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="col-12 {% if field.name == 'radio_input' %} col-radio-input {% endif %}">
            {% if field.field.required %}
                {% bootstrap_field field label_class='control-label required' %}
            {% else %}
                {% bootstrap_field field %}
            {% endif %}
       </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

However, the line self.fields['password'] kept throwing TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str which I have no idea why.
I tried to remove the required from the model itself like below
class User(AbstractUser):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

but then I have no idea how to make the password field mandatory on the create user without throwing the same error.

self.fields['password'].required = False  is wrong
because fields is just a list, not a dictionary, nor a class object, you can't access it using ['password'] syntax. Also since the list contains strings, not objects that have required property, you can't use .required either.
Actually you yourself are defining the fields list:
class UserEdit(UpdateView):
    model = User 
    fields = ['fullname', 'username','status','email','phone_number','role','program_studi','password']


You want to set the password field optional.
You can do it in two ways:

Create your own Form, making the password field optional and attach it to your view.
Get the form created by UpdateView class and change its required field (something you are trying to do)

class UserEdit(UpdateView):
    model = User 
    fields = ['fullname', 'username','status','email','phone_number','role','program_studi','password']
    template_name = 'user-management-edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user-management')
    
    # rest of your code
    # ...

    @override
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['password'].required = False
        return form


reference1
reference2
reference3


oh so that's why. All other similar problem were using self.fields['password'].required = False for their solution and it confuses me why it didn't work on my end. Your 2nd solution work flawlessly, many thanks!
